# ionic 3 theming the application on the fly

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, themes, ionic3

I was reading on theming the application for ionic 3 using variables.scss and in general using sass variables. Most of the stuff is here https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/theming-your-app/

Looking at examples like

```
$control-height: 40px;
```

i have 2 questions:
1. Where should i put these saas variables? in the same variables.scss under theme folder?

2. how would end user change this value so that app on the fly show the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Where should I put these saas variables? in the same `variables.scss` under theme folder?

A1: Yes

*variables.scss*

```
$control-height: 40px;
```

Q2. how would end user change this value so that app on the fly show the changes?

A2. Here is a great article about [**Dynamic Theming Your Ionic App**](https://devdactic.com/dynamic-theming-ionic/)